# Derive Lipschitz norm equality.

Tags: lipschitz-functions, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

I am reading the paper ["Spectral Normalization for Generative Adversarial Networks"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.05957). The Lipschitz norm is defined as 
$$\|f\|_{Lip}=\max \frac{\|f(x)-f(x')\|}{\|x-x'\|}$$
In section 2.1, they claim that $\|g\|_{Lip}=\sup_h\sigma(\nabla g(h))$ while $\sigma$ is the spectral norm of the matrix. How can we prove this?

Comment: What is $g(h)$?

Comment: @AngelaRichardson Sorry for the typo. Updated, all the notation are the same with the paper mentioned.

Comment: Why is $\nabla g(h)$ a matrix?

Comment: Hi, @AngelaRichardson, as defined in the origional paper. $g(h)=Wh$, I think it shoud be $\nabla g(h)=W^T$?